# How to find why task search is not responding

Tags: vba

I am new here and i am loosing my mind.
I inherited system maintenace for one client from previous system admin few months ago and we are upgrading system step by step. First step was to move emails to o365 exchange. Because of that we had to upgrade office suite on rdp to 2016 version because emails are read on server. That is another can of worms.

We have an app on RDP server that opens word for reporting. After word document has been created app inserts some macros in it. When user is done with it, clicks on Exit (or X button) call sub that is closing active word document.
Sub cheks if tasks.exists() and then closes open word document.
After upgrade from Word 2013 to Word 2016 we have random not responding problems and word doc is closing long time (sometimes after 30 min). It is not always so I am puzzled.

I try to recreate problem and i opened empty word doc, create sub and run it. Code looks like this (for testing purpose)

```
Sub test()
    a = 1
    For i = 1 To 10000
    If Tasks.Exists("MMMMM") Then
    Else
        a = a + 1
    End If
    Debug.Print (a)
    Next i
End Sub
```

`debug.print` is here to catch on which pass it stops responding but it did not help me at all.
Sometimes it runs several times without any problem, and sometimes it stops on first pass and i have to kill it from task manager. (word is not responding).

I have hit the wall and i need fresh pair of eyes.

Any help would be appreciated.

p.s. app is not made in the house so i can't change the way it works.

Br,
GK

I tried to disable AV but no change, all updates are up to date for Win (2016) and Office.
Only thing I have noticed is that when it break (stop respondig and cannot search trough tasks) is that Software Protection service stops.
Also colegue said that sometims Access app is closing for a very long time, and he said it was also happening before upgrade but rarely.

Comment: We are not telepathic.  Please provide the definition of Tasks.

Comment: Tasks.Exists method (Word)
Syntax:
expression. Exists( _Name_ )

Tasks object (Word)
A collection of Task objects that represents all the tasks currently running on the system.      I am sorry for that but i presumed that this is known method.

Comment: I've never used Tasks in Word VBA.  I have frequently used the Exists method of scripting.dictionaries.